# Query TFS to show all releases and whether or not it is set for approval. V 2017.3

Tags: sql, tfs

I need to run a query in sql that will show all the TFS releases from all projects and whether or not it is setup for pre relase approvals.  I see in the defaultcollection db there is the Release.tbl_ReleaseDefinition table, it has a lot of data but not approval info.  I do see the Release.tbl_DefinitionEnvironment and I see ApprovalOptions there, but that seems to be showing the approval info for every release created whereas I am needing info on release definitions only.

Comment: You should not query the TFS databases directly. The schema is intentionally undocumented, subject to change between versions, and is not available in the cloud. Use the REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Daniel pointed out, we highly not recommend you dig into TFS databased directly.

According to your description, you just need the approval info for all release definitions. Suggest you use **Rest API** to handle this.

For a single release, you could use below Rest API:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

It will return both  preDeployApprovals and postDeployApprovals, for example:

```
"preDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": false,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "approver": {
              "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
              "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/Identities/aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97",
              "_links": {
                "avatar": {
                  "href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.YjYxMjE5ZWQtODEwYS03OTU3LWJjYzAtMjQ0YTI5ZDk0ZjFl"
                }
              },
              "id": "aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97",
              "uniqueName": "fabfiber@outlook.com",
              "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_api/_common/identityImage?id=aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97",
              "descriptor": "aad.YjYxMjE5ZWQtODEwYS03OTU3LWJjYzAtMjQ0YTI5ZDk0ZjFl"
            },
            "id": 118
          }
        ],
```

More details please take a look at official doc here: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

For multiple release, you should use list: [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Hope this helps.